# Parola che definisca una frase come 'Houston, abbiamo un problema'

Tags: word-usage

> 'Houston, abbiamo un problema'.

Esiste una parola per indicare come una frase di questo tipo possa essere definita in italiano?

Voglio dire, è una frase pressoché mitica, tutti la usano quando in un processo si presenta un problema che, ancorché piccolo, rischia di mettere a repentaglio l'esito del processo stesso,  sebbene—sempre con riferimento al processo—abbia anche un valore esorcizzante.

Sono in cerca di una parola molto dotta, di quelle che usano o userebbero le persone colte.

Comment: “Citazione”?  :-)

Comment: [*Epifonema*?](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epifonema) Anche se non mi convince troppo se usata per l'esempio in questione. Può essere usata in altri casi.

Comment: ["Houston, abbiamo un problema"](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_13) è un riferimento alla missione di Apollo 13. Dopo l'esplosione di un serbatoio ossigeno durante la missione, il messaggio viene trasmesso sulla radio.

Answer (score 1):

Tecnicamente si tratta di un "eufemismo".

Gli astronauti avevano ben chiaro che rischiavano seriamente la pelle, dopo l'esplosione del serbatoio di ossigeno liquido. Probabilmente quando dissero qualla frase si consideravano già condannati a morte per l'impossibilità di manovrare e quindi di rientrare sulla Terra.

Invece di dirlo chiaramente hanno scelto una locuzione minimale: "a typical British understatement".

La frase "Houston, we have a problem" **NON** indica mai un "piccolo problema".

Comment: I tre astronauti non erano britannici. Non credo si sentissero già condannati a morte, anche se il rischio di morte era concreto. Infine non direi che la frase NON indica mai un "piccolo problema". Al contrario, non può indicare un problema molto serio, perché viene usata perlopiù scherzosamente.

Comment: Dimenticavo: quello di Lovell non era un understatement, bensì una comunicazione concisa e scevra di emotività, come ci si aspetta in ambito aeronautico e astronautico. Peraltro la frase originale è, come spiegato [qui (al secondo paragrafo)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_13#Popular_culture), "Houston, we've had a problem" ("Houston, abbiamo avuto un problema").

Comment: -1 Fantasia pura.